# Multiple dependency issues during RedHat's yum update

Tags: linux

As soon as I login I tried `sudo yum update` and it shows following errors. How do I solve this updates issue?

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-16-247 ~]$ sudo yum update
```

> Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
>   amzn-main/latest          
>   | 2.1 kB  00:00
>   
>   amzn-updates/latest         
>   | 2.3 kB  00:00
>    737 packages excluded due to
>   repository priority protections
>  Resolving Dependencies
>   --> Running transaction check
>   ---> Package aws-cfn-bootstrap.noarch 0:1.4-11.6.amzn1 will be updated
>   ---> Package aws-cfn-bootstrap.noarch 0:1.4-12.7.amzn1 will be an update
>   ---> Package aws-cli.noarch 0:1.10.46-1.40.amzn1 will be updated
>   ---> Package aws-cli.noarch 0:1.10.56-1.41.amzn1 will be an update
>   ---> Package bind-libs.x86_64 32:9.8.2-0.37.rc1.45.amzn1 will be updated
>   ---> Package bind-libs.x86_64 32:9.8.2-0.37.rc1.47.amzn1 will be an update
>   ---> Package bind-utils.x86_64 32:9.8.2-0.37.rc1.45.amzn1 will be updated
>   ---> Package bind-utils.x86_64 32:9.8.2-0.37.rc1.47.amzn1 will be an update
>   ---> Package curl.x86_64 0:7.40.0-8.58.amzn1 will be updated
>   ---> Package curl.x86_64 0:7.40.0-8.59.amzn1 will be an update
>   ---> Package db4.x86_64 0:4.7.25-18.11.amzn1 will be obsoleted
>   --> Processing Dependency: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit) for package: apr-util-
>   1.4.1-4.17.amzn1.x86_64
>   --> Processing Dependency: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit) for package: python27- libs-2.7.12-2.120.amzn1.x86_64
>   --> Processing Dependency: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit) for package: cyrus-sasl- lib-2.1.23-13.16.amzn1.x86_64
>   --> Processing Dependency: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit) for package: rpm-4.11.2-
>   2.73.amzn1.x86_64
>   --> Processing Dependency: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit) for package: ruby20-libs-
>   2.0.0.648-1.29.amzn1.x86_64
>   --> Processing Dependency: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit) for package: rpm-build-
>   4.11.2-2.73.amzn1.x86_64
>   --> Processing Dependency: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit) for package: iproute-
>   4.4.0-3.23.amzn1.x86_64
>   --> Processing Dependency: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit) for package: subversion- libs-1.9.4-2.55.amzn1.x86_64
>   --> Processing Dependency: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit) for package: pam-1.1.8-
>   12.33.amzn1.x86_64
>   --> Processing Dependency: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit) for package: subversion-
>   1.9.4-2.55.amzn1.x86_64
>   --> Processing Dependency: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit) for package: sendmail-
>   8.14.4-8.12.amzn1.x86_64
>   --> Processing Dependency: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit) for package: pam_ccreds- 10-4.9.amzn1.x86_64
>   --> Processing Dependency: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit) for package: libserf-
>   1.3.7-1.7.amzn1.x86_64
>   --> Processing Dependency: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit) for package: rpm-libs-
>   4.11.2-2.73.amzn1.x86_64
>   --> Processing Dependency: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit) for package: cyrus-sasl-
>   2.1.23-13.16.amzn1.x86_64
>   --> Processing Dependency: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit) for package: rpm-python27-
>   4.11.2-2.73.amzn1.x86_64
>   --> Processing Dependency: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit) for package: python26-
>   2.6.9-2.88.amzn1.x86_64
>   --> Processing Dependency: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit) for package: rpm-build- libs-4.11.2-2.73.amzn1.x86_64
>   ---> Package db4-utils.x86_64 0:4.7.25-18.11.amzn1 will be obsoleted
>   ---> Package dracut.noarch 0:004-336.28.amzn1 will be updated
>   ---> Package dracut.noarch 0:004-409.31.amzn1 will be an update
>
> amzn-updates/latest/filelists_db       |
>   3.3 MB  00:00
>    epel/x86_64/filelists_db        
>   | 7.2 MB  00:00  
>   ---> Package kernel.x86_64 0:4.4.19-29.55.amzn1 will be installed
>   ---> Package kernel-devel.x86_64 0:4.4.19-29.55.amzn1 will be installed
>   ---> Package kernel-headers.x86_64 0:4.4.15-25.57.amzn1 will be updated
>   ---> Package kernel-headers.x86_64 0:4.4.19-29.55.amzn1 will be an update
>   ---> Package kernel-tools.x86_64 0:4.4.15-25.57.amzn1 will be updated
>   ---> Package kernel-tools.x86_64 0:4.4.19-29.55.amzn1 will be an update
>   ---> Package libcurl.x86_64 0:7.40.0-8.58.amzn1 will be updated
>   ---> Package libcurl.x86_64 0:7.40.0-8.59.amzn1 will be an update
>   ---> Package libdb4.x86_64 0:4.8.30-13.el7 will be obsoleting
>   ---> Package libdb4-utils.x86_64 0:4.8.30-13.el7 will be obsoleting
>   ---> Package libevent.x86_64 0:2.0.18-1.11.amzn1 will be updated
>   ---> Package libevent.x86_64 0:2.0.21-4.19.amzn1 will be an update
>   ---> Package libgcrypt.x86_64 0:1.5.3-12.18.amzn1 will be updated
>   ---> Package libgcrypt.x86_64 0:1.5.3-12.19.amzn1 will be an update
>   ---> Package mysql-config.x86_64 0:5.5.46-1.10.amzn1 will be updated
>   ---> Package mysql-config.x86_64 0:5.5.51-1.11.amzn1 will be an update
>   ---> Package python26.x86_64 0:2.6.9-2.86.amzn1 will be updated
>   ---> Package python26.x86_64 0:2.6.9-2.88.amzn1 will be an update
>   --> Processing Dependency: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit) for package: python26-
>   2.6.9-2.88.amzn1.x86_64
>   ---> Package python26-libs.x86_64 0:2.6.9-2.86.amzn1 will be updated
>   ---> Package python26-libs.x86_64 0:2.6.9-2.88.amzn1 will be an update
>   ---> Package python27.x86_64 0:2.7.10-4.122.amzn1 will be updated
>   ---> Package python27.x86_64 0:2.7.12-2.120.amzn1 will be an update
>   ---> Package python27-boto.noarch 0:2.39.0-1.0.amzn1 will be updated
>   ---> Package python27-boto.noarch 0:2.42.0-1.1.amzn1 will be an update
>   ---> Package python27-botocore.noarch 0:1.4.36-1.56.amzn1 will be updated
>   ---> Package python27-botocore.noarch 0:1.4.46-1.58.amzn1 will be an update 
>   ---> Package python27-devel.x86_64 0:2.7.10-4.122.amzn1 will be updated
>   ---> Package python27-devel.x86_64 0:2.7.12-2.120.amzn1 will be an update
>   ---> Package python27-libs.x86_64 0:2.7.10-4.122.amzn1 will be updated
>   ---> Package python27-libs.x86_64 0:2.7.12-2.120.amzn1 will be an update
>   --> Processing Dependency: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit) for package: python27- libs-2.7.12-2.120.amzn1.x86_64
>   --> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/db_stat for package: rpm-4.11.2-
>   2.73.amzn1.x86_64
>   --> Processing Conflict: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 conflicts filesystem <
>
> 3
>   --> Finished Dependency Resolution
>
> Error: Package: python26-2.6.9-2.88.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-updates)
>       Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
>       Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64
>   (installed)
>       libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
>       Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64
>   (epel)
>       ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
>
> Error: Package: rpm-4.11.2-2.73.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
>       Requires: /usr/bin/db_stat
>     
>   Removing: db4-utils-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
>        Not found 
>     Obsoleted By:
>   libdb4-utils-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
>      
>   Not found
>
> Error: Package: iproute-4.4.0-3.23.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
>       Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
>       Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64
>   (installed)
>       libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
>       Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64
>   (epel)
>       ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
>
> Error: Package: ruby20-libs-2.0.0.648-1.29.amzn1.x86_64
>   (installed)
>      Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
>       Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64
>   (installed)
>       libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
>       Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64
>   (epel)
>       ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
>
> Error: Package: rpm-build-4.11.2-2.73.amzn1.x86_64 (@amzn-main)
>       Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
>       Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64
>   (installed)
>       libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
>       Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64
>   (epel)
>       ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
>
> Error: Package: rpm-python27-4.11.2-2.73.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
>       Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
>       Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64
>   (installed)
>       libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
>       Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64
>   (epel)
>       ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
>
> Error: Package: python27-libs-2.7.12-2.120.amzn1.x86_64
>   (amzn-updates)
>      Requires:
>   libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
>      Removing:
>   db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
>      
>   libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
>      Obsoleted By:
>   libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
>      
>   ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
>
> Error: libdb4 conflicts with filesystem-2.4.30-3.8.amzn1.x86_64
>
> Error: Package: rpm-build-libs-4.11.2-2.73.amzn1.x86_64
>   (installed)
>      Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
>       Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64
>   (installed)
>       libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
>       Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64
>   (epel)
>       ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
>
> Error: Package: sendmail-8.14.4-8.12.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
>       Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
>       Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64
>   (installed)
>       libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
>       Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64
>   (epel)
>       ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
>
> Error: Package: cyrus-sasl-lib-2.1.23-13.16.amzn1.x86_64
>   (installed)
>      Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
>       Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64
>   (installed)
>       libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
>       Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64
>   (epel)
>       ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
>
> Error: Package: pam-1.1.8-12.33.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
>       Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
>       Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64
>   (installed)
>       libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
>       Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64
>   (epel)
>       ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
>
> Error: Package: subversion-1.9.4-2.55.amzn1.x86_64 (@amzn-updates)
>       Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
>       Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64
>   (installed)
>       libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
>       Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64
>   (epel)
>       ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
>
> Error: Package: apr-util-1.4.1-4.17.amzn1.x86_64 (@amzn-main)
>       Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
>       Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64
>   (installed)
>       libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
>       Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64
>   (epel)
>       ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
>
> Error: Package: rpm-libs-4.11.2-2.73.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
>       Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
>       Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64
>   (installed)
>       libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
>       Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64
>   (epel)
>       ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
>
> Error: Package: pam_ccreds-10-4.9.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
>       Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
>       Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64
>   (installed)
>       libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
>       Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64
>   (epel)
>       ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
>
> Error: Package: subversion-libs-1.9.4-2.55.amzn1.x86_64
>   (@amzn-updates)
>      Requires:
>   libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
>      Removing:
>   db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
>      
>   libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
>      Obsoleted By:
>   libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
>      
>   ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
>
> Error: Package: cyrus-sasl-2.1.23-13.16.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
>       Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
>       Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64
>   (installed)
>       libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
>       Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64
>   (epel)
>       ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
>
> Error: Package: libserf-1.3.7-1.7.amzn1.x86_64 (@amzn-main)
>       Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
>       Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64
>   (installed)
>       libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
>       Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64
>   (epel)
>       ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
>
> Error: Package: rpm-4.11.2-2.73.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
>       Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
>       Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64
>   (installed)
>       libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
>       Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64
>   (epel)
>       ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
>
> You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
>   You
>   could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

`[ec2-user@ip-172-31-16-247 ~]$`

Comment: I have the same problem on AWS server.

Answer (score 29):

There is a conflict between epel and ami packages. The thing to do (since you are on AMI) is to disable other repositories first, run clean + update, then renable them (for one-off install/upgrades on a per-package basis).

```
yum-config-manager --disable epel
yum clean all
yum update
yum-config-manager --enable epel
```

Comment: OK thanks but that doesn't help me resolve the epel dependency. This simply goes *around* the problem.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. You definitely saved me a lot of hours. :)

Answer (score 6):

For me, the solution was to exclude **libdb** from the *epel* repository by updating **/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo** like so:

```
[epel]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/$basearch
metalink=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-7&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-7
exclude=libdb*
```

Answer (score -3):

Please see the errors after executing the sudo yum update

```
Error: Package: apr-util-1.4.1-4.17.amzn1.x86_64 (@amzn-main)
           Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
               libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: httpd-tools-2.2.31-1.8.amzn1.x86_64 (@amzn-main)
           Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
               libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
Error: libdb4 conflicts with filesystem-2.4.30-3.8.amzn1.x86_64
Error: Package: pam_ccreds-10-4.9.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
           Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
               libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: cyrus-sasl-2.1.23-13.16.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
           Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
               libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: sendmail-8.14.4-9.14.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
           Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
               libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: rpm-4.11.2-2.73.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
           Requires: libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Removing: db4-4.7.25-18.11.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
               libdb-4.7.so()(64bit)
           Obsoleted By: libdb4-4.8.30-13.el7.x86_64 (epel)
              ~libdb-4.8.so()(64bit)
```

You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest